std::chrono::gps_time (gps_clock) set with from_string
this is a follow up question  to c++20 gps_clock initilize from string.
I have on my OS (openSuse Tumbelweed) GCC 14.
I need to initialize a std::chrono:gps_clock from a string, therefore the following code:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::chrono::gps_time<std::chrono::seconds> GPS;

    std::stringstream neededGPSTime("2024-01-01 00:00:00");

    std::chrono::from_stream(neededGPSTime, "%F %T", GPS);

    std::cout << "Needed GPS Time:      " << neededGPSTime.str() << std::endl << "Time of GPS variable: " <<  GPS << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

The output is:
Needed GPS Time:      2024-01-01 00:00:00
Time of GPS variable: 2024-01-01 00:00:18
*** Finished ***

Obviously the date-time string is considered UTC. Is this really intended?
How then to initialize a gps_clock directly from a string?
Of course the workaround given in the link above is working, but I thought it might be easier..
Thanks,
Johannes

Not enough to be an answer, but just some info.. GPS always/only works in UTC. The protocol and the concept as a whole has no knowledge of timezones.

Although that's true, chrono::parse supports parsing an offset, and the resulting value will be adjusted by that offset. e.g. parsing "2024-09-04 01:00:00 +0100" will yield 2024-09-04 00:00:00. That wasn't the cause of the gcc bug encountered here though.

This turns out to just be a bug in gcc, and it is going to be fixed for the next release.  Thank you for bringing it to our attention.
Your code is correct.
In the interim the answer you reference is a good workaround.
